# What is the default Rails version when I use "gem rails" in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In the Gemfile, I wrote `gem 'rails'`.

`gem list` returns `rails (3.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.0.9)`

So if I call `rails s`, which version of Rails would it use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it out by executing :

```
rails -v
```

Comment: no, i'm looking for the version of rails that is being used by the project ,

Comment: It will use the default one unless you specified differently in your Gemfile.

Comment: Which is the default one from rails (3.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.0.9)?

Comment: It should be 3.1.3, just use rails -v to make sure

Comment: Is rails -v related to Gemfile , gem 'rails' or gem 'rails-3.1.1' ?

Comment: Check your Gemfile. If rails version is not specified inside, then use  'rails -v'. This will be your version used for your project.

Comment: Like @spyrosP said if your Rails version is not specified in the Gemfile then it uses the one you have set as default on your machine.You know that you can have more than one rails version installed and select which one to use.

Comment: @SpyrosP that's wrong. If you create project with rails 3.1.1 after that rails 3.1.3 is released and you install it with `gem update` or something other then `bundle update rails` inside your project path rails command without `bundle exec` should use last installed version in your system not version specified for project.

Answer (score 1):

You define it in your `Gemfile` by the line:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.1'
```

If the version information is missing, it will be the version that was the newest one when the command `bundle install` was run. The information is stored in the file `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: Sometimes, an upgrade is not that easy, and you want to fix the older one. There may be dependencies that older versions of Gems you are using are no more compliant with the new version. This will not be a problem with 3.1.1 versus 3.1.3 :-)

Answer (score 1):

By default it will use first version from `gem list` command, which is the version with highest number.

Comment: if you don't put sepecific version in your Gemfile then it is using default which is the newest installed wich in your case is 3.1.3

Answer (score 1):

If you have any project with `Gemfile` you need to run commands with `bundle exec command`. Then, the version of the command will be equal version from `Gemfile.lock`.

Otherwise, if you have

- rails 3.0 `project1` and
- rails 3.1 `project2`

… then you should try to use rails 3.0 in `project1` with `rails`. It will be last version from `gem list` `rails (3.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.0.9) => 3.1.3`.

If you use `bundle exec rails` it will be 3.0 (version from `Gemfile.lock`).